# Flink StreamingFileSink - ParquetAvroWriters

Tags: apache-flink, parquet, flink-streaming

I am using Flink - Streaming file sink to write incoming data S3 buckets. My code works with `forRowFormat` options perfectly.
Now I am trying to  setup `forBulkFormat` option to write data in parquet format to S3. My sink function is as follows.

```java
private static SinkFunction<Pojo> getS3Sink() {

   final StreamingFileSink<Pojo> sink = StreamingFileSink
        .forBulkFormat(new Path(s3SinkPath),
                ParquetAvroWriters.forSpecificRecord(Pojo.class)
        )

        .withBucketAssigner(new CustomBucketAssigner())
        .build();
   return sink;
}
```

I am running this whole setup on IntelliJ.
When I run this code I am getting following error :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/FileOutputFormat
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016) ~[?:?]
>
> at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[?:?]
>
> at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800) ~[?:?]
>
> at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698) ~[?:?]
>
> at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621) ~[?:?]
>
> at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579) ~[?:?]
>
> at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[?:?]
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[?:?]
>
> at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.(ParquetWriter.java:285) ~[parquet-hadoop-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
>
> at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter$Builder.build(ParquetWriter.java:641) ~[parquet-hadoop-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
>
> at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.avro.ParquetAvroWriters.createAvroParquetWriter(ParquetAvroWriters.java:87) ~[flink-parquet_2.12-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
>
> at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.avro.ParquetAvroWriters.lambda$forSpecificRecord$824091b3$1(ParquetAvroWriters.java:49) ~[flink-parquet_2.12-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
>
> at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetWriterFactory.create(ParquetWriterFactory.java:57) ~[flink-parquet_2.12-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
>
> at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.BulkBucketWriter.openNew(BulkBucketWriter.java:69) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
>
> at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.OutputStreamBasedPartFileWriter$OutputStreamBasedBucketWriter.openNewInProgressFile(OutputStreamBasedPartFileWriter.java:83) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]

Flink documentation does not talk about additional configuration required to handle output format. Can you please help ?

Following are the maven dependencies :

```xml
<flink.version>1.11.2</flink.version>
<scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
<avro.version>1.10.2</avro.version>
<flink.format.parquet.version>1.12.0</flink.format.parquet.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-avro</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.format.parquet.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-parquet_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-s3-fs-hadoop</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please specify which dependencies are being used ?

Comment: Updated the original post with dependencies, thanks.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you don't need to specify `parquet-avro` dependency as it will be transitively resolved by Flink-parquet. Moreover, Flink-parquet of version 1.11.2 depends on older paqruet-avro version(1.10)

Comment: Does not work :-( , few dependencies are transitive but it brings parquet-format-structures and parquet-column dependencies additionally.

Comment: @SwapnilKhante Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this issue as well and was able to resolve it by including a `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core` dependency, as well as the `org.apache.flink:flink-hadoop-compatibility_2.12`. Which populated all the required hadoop classes into the class path.

It might also be worth noting that the [flink docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/connectors/datastream/formats/parquet/) currently suggest excluding some transitive dependencies from `parquet-avro`, which might help with any collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Building on AlecBrooks's answer, I also had to include `hadoop-common`. If you're using `hadoop-client` (a common test dependency for Flink projects to be able to run locally) that actually contains `hadoop-common` and `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core`. The scope for any of the dependencies I mention with "hadoop" in their name should be provided if you're running with a Hadoop installation. If you're just using the connectors (standalone), then you'll need Hadoop classes.

If you're using Maven your POM will have those mentioned in the docs:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-parquet</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.2</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>it.unimi.dsi</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastutil</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

As well as:

```xml
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-hadoop-compatibility -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-hadoop-compatibility_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

And finally with either the minimum Hadoop dependencies:

```xml
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
        <!-- Exclusions based on Flink source -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.reload4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>reload4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-reload4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Or the single larger dependency:

```xml
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

For more information on how to add the Hadoop classes when you're not running in standalone (local IDE) mode, please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75962713/edit)