# How to fix Flink pipeline NoClassDefFoundError : "org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration"

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I implemented an Apache Flink pipeline and got the following error:

```
NoClassDefFoundError : "org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration"
```

Does this mean I am missing a dependency, or is it a classloading problem?

[Flink-Docs:Debugging_Classloading](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/ops/debugging/debugging_classloading/)

Answer (score 2):

If you're running a standalone pipeline (no hadoop installation, often the case when running locally) you need to provide the missing classes with your code. You can add `hadoop-common` to provide them. In some cases you'll also need additional dependencies for flink-parquet, so it's popular to include `hadoop-client`. See this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67369752/flink-streamingfilesink-parquetavrowriters) if you run into problems for Parquet.

The scope of these is `provided` if you only run in standalone mode for unit tests. Otherwise it's `compile` (default).

```xml
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
        <!-- Exclusions based on Flink source -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.reload4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>reload4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-reload4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Or:

```xml
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Otherwise, if you have a Hadoop installation that should provide the classes, so ensure the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` is set correctly in your environment. See [this page](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/configuration/advanced/#hadoop-dependencies) in the Flink docs (I think it will be updated soon), and [this tutorial](https://phpfog.com/creating-hadoop-docker-image/) for how to add Hadoop to a Docker image which should give you an idea how to install it and set the class path. Below is the important stuff, and I will update as I learn more.

```
FROM flink

ARG hadoop_version="3.3.5"
ARG hadoop_arch=""
# set hadoop_arch to "-aarch64" for 64bit systems "" otherwise

ENV HADOOP_HOME /opt/hadoop/hadoop-$hadoop_version
WORKDIR /opt/hadoop

# Install hadoop
# See https://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html
RUN \
  # download the release hadoop-X.Y.Z-src.tar.gz from a mirror site.
  wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/hadoop/common/hadoop-$hadoop_version/hadoop-$hadoop_version$hadoop_arch.tar.gz && \
\
  # download the signature file hadoop-X.Y.Z-src.tar.gz.asc from Apache.
  wget https://downloads.apache.org/hadoop/common/hadoop-$hadoop_version/hadoop-$hadoop_version$hadoop_arch.tar.gz.asc && \
\
  # download the Hadoop KEYS file.
  wget https://downloads.apache.org/hadoop/common/KEYS && \
\
  # verify the download
  gpg --import ./KEYS && \
  gpg --verify hadoop-$hadoop_version$hadoop_arch.tar.gz.asc hadoop-$hadoop_version$hadoop_arch.tar.gz && \
\
  # Unarchive
  tar -xzf hadoop-$hadoop_version$hadoop_arch.tar.gz && \
\
  # Cleanup
  rm hadoop-$hadoop_version$hadoop_arch.tar.gz && \
  rm hadoop-$hadoop_version$hadoop_arch.tar.gz.asc && \
  rm KEYS
  
# Set JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.sh, update path, etc.
RUN \
  echo "export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME" >> $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh && \
  echo "PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH
ENV HADOOP_CLASSPATH $(find $HADOOP_HOME -name '*.jar' | xargs echo | tr ' ' ':')
ENV HADOOP_CONF_DIR $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop

# Reset WORKDIR
WORKDIR $FLINK_HOME
```

Comment: Unless you use the DataSet API (which you shouldn't, given that it's deprecated and you should use the DataStream API or Table/SQL API), you have no need to add `flink-hadoop-compatibility_${scala.binary.version}`.

If you add `hadoop-common`, you often also need to add `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core`. Common exclusion for all Hadoop dependencies are `org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper`, `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12` and `log4j:log4j`

Comment: I will update my answer based on your feedback; I'm working on it RN, so expect another edit with a timestamp later than this comment.